# iPhone/iPad WebView Example

Tags: objective-c, iphone, uiwebview

Where can I find a simple compilable example on how to create and use a UIWebView?

Any non-interface builder examples?

Comment: Just give up and learn Objective-C and Interface Builder. It's a harsh advice but that's just inevitable if you want to write an iPhone app. Think of it as a way to learn a new language and a new perspective.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

```
UIWebView *webView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480)];
[webView setDelegate:self];

NSString *urlAddress = @"http://www.google.com/";
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlAddress];
NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[webView loadRequest:requestObj];

[self.view addSubview:webView];
```

Answer (score 1):

```
WebView - Add the Delegate

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIWebView *WebView;

NSString *fullURL = @"http://facebook.com/";
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:fullURL];
NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[_WebView loadRequest:requestObj];
```